# Is't possible to merge two DevOps accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I wish move from Microsoft personal DevOps Account to my O365 Account Tenant where I run Azure, too. 
Is't possible to mantein the benefits, too?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that transfer Transfer Azure DevOps to New Azure Account

1. Add a AAD member which is a Microsoft account to your Azure DevOps organization.
2. Add this AAD member to Project collection Administrators group.
3. Log into the Azure portal and connect the organization to AAD.
4. Then you could login to your Azure DevOps organization with AAD member

Answer (score 0):

To merge two Azure DevOps account, there is no such kind of feature at the moment.

A related user voice here:

> **make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365365/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1.html

Any other 3rd party extension or tool will not keep history info. Suggest you use two organization separately to keep history. Or manually merge it without history.